# AEM 6.5 WKND repo build issues

Tags: maven, aem

I created a maven project in batch mode by typing the following command:

```sh
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=22 -DgroupId=com.adobe.aem.guides -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DappsFolderName=wknd -DartifactId=aem-guides-wknd -Dpackage=com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd -DartifactName="WKND Sites Project" -DcomponentGroupName=WKND -DconfFolderName=wknd -DcontentFolderName=wknd -DcssId=wknd -DisSingleCountryWebsite=n -Dlanguage_country=en_us -DoptionAemVersion=6.5.0 -DoptionDispatcherConfig=none -DoptionIncludeErrorHandler=n -DoptionIncludeExaples=y -DoptionIncludeFrontendModule=y -DpackageGroup=wknd -DsiteName="WKND Site"
```

when I type `mvn -PautoInstallSinglePackage clean install`

I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project aem-guides-wknd.ui.apps: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.adobe.aem.guides:aem-guides-wknd.ui.apps:content-package:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.adobe.aem.guides:aem-guides-wknd.ui.frontend:zip:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

From the error I guess and when I searched that there is no such **artifactid** in maven repository. Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

If your sole requirement is to build the wknd project, then just download the maven project from git and import it as a maven project in eclipse. After that build it. That should hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: Are there instructions on how to do this? I keep getting BUILD FAILURE when I try to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have below options :
1.You Can check your root pom.xml file. There you can comment out ui.frontend module i.e. `<!--module>  ui.frontend  </module-->`. After hat you can run your package build command.
2. you can got to each sub-module like core,ui.appss and run following command to build individually `mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle`
Let me know if this helps or will look into some other solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I continue to get the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside parent pom.xml comment dispatcher module 
example :
<modules>
 <module>all</module>
 <module>core</module>
 <module>ui.frontend</module>
 <module>ui.apps</module>
 <module>ui.apps.structure</module>
 <module>ui.config</module>
 <module>ui.content</module>
 <module>ui.content.sample</module>
 <module>it.tests</module>
 **<!--<module>dispatcher</module>-->**
 <module>ui.tests</module>
 </modules>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).